# Can't start httpd as root

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, awstats

Even when running httpd as root, I get this error:

```
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:100
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:100
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I tried changing the ports, even to ones not blocked by iptables and I still get the same error (according to "netstat -an"). Reinstalled and same deal. I'm running CentOS 5.3 x86_64.

Nginx is running on my port 80. I just want to run Apache as a backend so I can view AWStats online. A solution to either this or the above problem would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a case of SELinux getting in the way.  You should be able to check if it is running by running "/usr/sbin/getenforce".  If it says "Enforcing", you could try disabling it by running "sudo /usr/sbin/setforce 0" then restart apache and see if you get the same results.